# Remove special characters in C

Tags: c

I have to write C program without using any include libraries. For my requirement get command line arguments and write to a file. When I write to file, it will write special characters(Junk). Please provide me solution for this. Can use only read() and write() functions only.

```
#define O_WRONLY 01
#define O_APPEND 02000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND, 0);
    if(fd < 0 )
        return 1;
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        char bufMsg[] ="Parameters are missing!\n" ;
        write(1, bufMsg, sizeof(bufMsg));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
        {
            write(fd, argv[i],sizeof(argv[i]));
            write(fd, " ",1 );
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        close(fd);
    }  
    return 1;     
}
```

Comment: Share some sample input and output. What exactly are these special characters? Put in the relevant sections of your code which are causing this behavior.

Comment: The key to this is in the first four words of your post. **You have to write**. Please make an effort to do so. Once you've tried, and run into problems, you can explain the problem, **post your code**, and ask a specific question about the problem and we can try to help. We're not going to do it for you. Good luck.

Comment: What makes you confident that `sizeof(argv[i])` is actually the number of byte in `argv[i]`. Perhaps you want to get the length of the string pointed to by `argv[i]`?

Comment: Yes I want to exact length of input string and write exact input string.

Comment: `sizeof(argv[i])` is size of pointer to char (`sizeof(char*)`), not length of string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with helping you with the first part of your problem. As BLUEPIXY points out, `sizeof(argv[i])` is **size of pointer to char** `(sizeof(char*))`, **not length of string**. So, you can either include `string.h` and use the `strlen` function or write your own. Using the `strlen` function, you could do:

```
...
write(1, bufMsg, strlen (bufMsg));
...
write(fd, argv[i], strlen (argv[i]));
```

You may also want to fix:

```
write(1, "\n", 1);  /* I suspect write(fd, "\n", 1); was intended */
```

While we are helping, are you sure you want to redefine:

```
#define O_WRONLY 01
#define O_APPEND 02000
```

The values may be perfectly correct (I didn't check), but why would you want to do that in the first place? The header files already define them for you.

In response to your comment of not being able to include any libraries, while unclear if you mean header files or something else, you can get the length of the string in a number of ways without using `strlen`. For example you can use the following `slen` function instead of `strlen`:

```
size_t slen (char *str) 
{
    char *p = str;
    size_t ln = 0;

    if (!p)
        return -1;

    while (*p++ != '\0')
        ln++;

    return ln;
}
```

Following further you comments. In order to compile and run the program, you are **at minimum**, required to include header files necessary to `open` and `write` to your file. Otherwise your application will not compile. You can rely on exiting the application to close the open file descriptor, but since the header files needed also provide `close` you can include `close` for completeness. With that proviso, a minimum functional approach to your program that only makes user of `open` and `write` would be:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t slen (char *str)
{
    size_t ln = 0;
    if (!str) return -1;
    while (*str++ != '\0') ln++;
    return ln;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        char bufMsg[] ="Error, incorrect arguments.\n  usage: prog arg_1 arg_2 arg_3\n";
        write (1, bufMsg, slen (bufMsg));
        return 1;
    }

    fd = open ("testfile.txt", 
                O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND,
                S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
    if (fd < 0 )
    {
        char fileMsg[] = "Error opening file\n";
        write (1, fileMsg, slen (fileMsg));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            write (fd, argv[i], slen (argv[i]));
            write (fd, " ", 1);
        }
        write (fd, "\n", 1);
        close (fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

build:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/ow onlywrite.c
```

run:

```
./bin/ow Argument_1 Argument_2 Argument_3
```

output:

```
$ ls -al testfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 34 Jul 30 02:52 testfile.txt
$ cat testfile.txt
Argument_1 Argument_2 Argument_3
```

Comment: I will not able to use any include libraries!

Comment: See my last edit. When you say I will not be able to include libraries, do you mean **header files**?

Comment: yes, I meant header files like stdio.h, string.h.. etc

Comment: @user3886044:: How are you using "open", "write" and "close" then, if you are not including stdio, etc, etc ?

Comment: No luck yet!, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, see my last edit. You cannot compile an application in C that makes use of `open` and `write` without including the required header files. A minimum example is provided.

Comment: David C. Rankin: Thanks for the your solutions. We can compile c programs with out header files if we just using read/write functions. You can try compiling and run given my sample. If I use header files, I will not able use shell forge. This is only for uni studies.

Comment: I'll try it. I always like minimalist solutions -- but no headers -- man -- that's taking it to the extreme... How does one open a file with just read/write?

Comment: Fixed! write(1, bufMsg, sizeof(bufMsg));

int strlength(const char *str)
{
        const char *s;

        for (s = str; *s; ++s)
                ;
        return (s - str);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
#define O_WRONLY 01
#define O_APPEND 02000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND, 0);
    if(fd < 0 )
        return 1;
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        char bufMsg[] ="Parameters are missing!\n" ;
        write(1, bufMsg, sizeof(bufMsg));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
    {
        write(fd, argv[i],strlength(argv[i]));
        write(fd, " ",1 );
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    close(fd);
    }  
    return 1;     
}

int strlength(const char *str)
{
    const char *s;

    for (s = str; *s; ++s)
            ;
    return (s - str);
}
```